# How can I centre-align a QLabel in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

```
#Created using PyQt5 and Python 3.5 on Windows 7
from sys import (exit, argv)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap, QFont)
from random import choice

#Word list for the words the user will attempt to guess
words = ['Captivity', 'America', 'Europe', 'Federal', 'Gluten', 'Ridiculous', 'Automatic', 'Television', 'Difficult', 'Severe', 'Interesting', 'Indonesia', 'Industrial',
         'Automotive', 'President', 'Terrestrial', 'Academic', 'Comedic', 'Comical', 'Genuine', 'Suitcase', 'Vietnam', 'Achievement', 'Careless', 'Monarchy', 'Monetary', 
         'Quarantine', 'Supernatural', 'Illuminate', 'Optimal', 'Application', 'Scientist', 'Software', 'Hardware', 'Program', 'Colonial', 'Algorithm', 'Intelligent']

#Creates the main widget which will contain everything else
class hangman(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #Creates the QLabel 'background' which will contain the white background
        self.background = QLabel(self)
        #Uses QPixmap to place the background into the QLabel 'background'
        self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.jpg').scaled(162, 352, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.background.move(0.5, 0.5)


        #Creates the QLabel 'image' which will contain the image of the hangman
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        #Uses QPixmap to insert the image of the hangman into the QLabel 'image'
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_7.png').scaled(78, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.image.move(39, 0.5)

        #Chooses random word from list 'words'
        word = choice(words)  
        #Creates a blank version of the chosen word 
        blank_word = ''
        for i in word:
            blank_word += '__ '

        self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
        self.blank_word_label.move(20,200)
        #This doesn't work!!!
        self.blank_word_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)






        #Sets where on the screen the window will open and the size of the window respectively using x and y coordinates
        self.setGeometry(1427, 30, 162, 231)
        #Locks the size of the window and make it impossible for the user to change it
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Hangman')
        #Sets the window icon to the image file 'icon.png' located in the same folder as the source file
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()





if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Begins the execution of the QApplication

    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = hangman()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

This is a hangman game project that I am working on using PyQt5 and Python on a Windows 7 Machine. I have created two little projects using the same setup already (A coin flip simulator and a die roll simulator). I am still a beginner and this is my third and most recent "major" project. I am unable to get the blank version of the word to align to the center of the main window to can't seem to figure it out. Any help/advice is welcome. :)

Comment: To which QLabel you mean, you can also center the text if it is small in size to its geometry.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/auPWF

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to align the blank version of the word the user is guessing to the center of the window because all the words have different lengths.

Comment: You should change the font size, try the solution that you have proposed and if it fails, let me know to look for another one. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you. FernAndr's suggestion worked. It isn't complete yet so it is likely that I will change some things.

Comment: What about using layouts? And please provide a minimal example, removing everything that is not necessary to show the effect. Makes debugging easier for us and for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem you are having is that you are not giving an explicit width to your label, and hence it just uses whatever space it needs. I would set the label width to the main widget width, then move it only vertically, i.e.:

```
self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
self.blank_word_label.setFixedWidth(162)
# Or, if you reorder your code so that your self.setGeometry(1427, ...) line occurs before this code, you could do directly:
# self.blank_word_label.setFixedWidth(self.width())
self.blank_word_label.move(0, 200)
self.blank_word_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Alternatively, I think you could let the label to be autosized, then adjust its left based on its width and the parent width. In any case, for it to be centered, you should always make sure that
`label.width() + 2 * label.left() == form.width()`. This should work even if label.left() is negative / label.width() is higher than form.width() for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to have solved the problem. I'm sorry I can't upvote because i don't have enough reputation but this worked for me. Thanks again. :)